# Injecting a class using DI: failed to open stream

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, namespaces, factory

I have a class named `ModelFactory` which is supposed to return an instance of `Model` object. But for some reason, PHP can't seem to find it.

> Warning: require_once(../../../../../model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Here's my `ModelFactory` class which is loaded via DI for reference:

```php
namespace jas\Pdf\Factory;

require_once "../../../../../model.php";

use Model;

class ModelFactory
{
    /**
     * @return Model
     */
    public function create(){
        return new Model(false);
    }
}
```

And here's my `Model` class, which is 5 levels above `ModelFactory` class, loaded via `require_once`:

```php
class Model
{

    public function __construct($serverRequest = false)
    {
        if(!$serverRequest){
            $this->checkIfLocal();
        }
        $this->conn = $this->connectToDB();
    }
}
```

I'm kind of confused. Is the PHP throwing the error due to `Model` class not having a namespace, or is it because `ModelFactory` namespace conflicting with the file paths? Thank you so much for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by referring to this question:
[PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

I used `__DIR__` as the baseline of the path. Applying this, the path looks now like this:

```php
namespace jas\Pdf\Factory;

require_once __DIR__."/../../../../../model.php";

use Model;

class ModelFactory
{
    /**
     * @return Model
     */
    public function create(){
        return new Model(false);
    }
}
```

And so, the class is now properly loaded.